# Hibernate HQL Query : How to set a Collection as a named parameter of a Query?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Given the following HQL Query:

```
FROM
    Foo
WHERE
    Id = :id AND
    Bar IN (:barList)
```

I set `:id` using the Query object's `setInteger()` method.

I would like to set `:barList` using a `List` of objects, but looking at the Hibernate documentation and list of methods I cannot see an obvious choice of which to use. Any ideas?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use `Query.setParameterList()`, [Javadoc here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection%29).

There are four variants to pick from.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! I completely overlooked this when looking at the the JavaDoc.

Comment: D: Oh noes, broken link (...painfully typical of the JBoss docs)

Comment: That only works if you are using a hibernate Query object, but won't work if you import `javax.persistence.Query`. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 33):

I'm not sure about HQL, but in JPA you just call the query's `setParameter` with the parameter and collection.

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Peron p WHERE name IN (:names)");
q.setParameter("names", names);
```

where `names` is the collection of names you're searching for

```
Collection<String> names = new ArrayList<String();
names.add("Joe");
names.add("Jane");
names.add("Bob");
```

Answer (score 1):

In [TorpedoQuery](http://torpedoquery.org) it look like this

```
Entity from = from(Entity.class);
where(from.getCode()).in("Joe", "Bob");
Query<Entity> select = select(from);
```

Comment: How does that answer the question? Please don't post links to your project if they don't address the problem directly.

Comment: It generate an hql query with a in condition