# JPA where clause any

Tags: java, jpa

In JPA, the query is:

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select o from Product o WHERE o.category = :value");
q.setParameter("category", category);
```

How can I set category to any category in JPA? So if the null category passed, I simple ignore the category parameter, select all products.

Comment: this guide has some examples using `Criteria`s as well as other more hardcoded alternatives. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_quick_guide.htm

Answer (score 19):

> How can I set category to any category in JPA? So if the null category passed, I simple ignore the category parameter, select all products.

You'll have to build the query dynamically here. With HQL (this is a simplified example):

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
StringBuffer hql = new StringBuffer("from Product p");
boolean first = true;

if (category != null) {
    hql.append(first ? " where " : " and ");
    hql.append("p.category = :category");
    params.put("category", category);
}

// And so on...

Query query = session.createQuery(hql.toString());

Iterator<String> iter = params.keySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String name = iter.next();
    Object value = params.get(name);
    query.setParameter(name, value);
}

List results = query.list()
```

But, actually, my recommendation would be to use the Criteria API here:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Product.class);
if (category != null) {
    criteria.add(Expression.eq("category", category);
}
// And so on...
List results = criteria.list();
```

Much simpler for complicated dynamic queries.

Comment: Criteria is a better solution for dynamic queries. Expression.eq is deprecated, instead you can use Restrictions.eq

Comment: this guide has some examples using `Criteria`s as well as other more hardcoded alternatives. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_quick_guide.htm

Answer (score 4):

To archive parameters become optional you can write a query without having to use the Criteria API:

```
select o from Product o WHERE :value is null or :value='' or o.category = :value
```

Comment: Hello, I'm wondering if is possible to make this kind of evaluation with collections like the query from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570229/hibernate-hql-query-how-to-set-a-collection-as-a-named-parameter-of-a-query. So this query isn't working in my project as follow: FROM
    Foo
WHERE
    Id = :id AND (:barlist is null or Bar in (:barlist))

Answer (score 2):

You are right almost with small change.

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select o from Product o WHERE o.category = :value");
query.setParameter("value", category);
```

in setParamater **"value"** (exact text) should match with **":value"** in query.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I set category to any category in JPA? So if the null category
>   passed, I simple ignore the category parameter, select all products.

You can set the category to "%".
if (category == null) query.setParameter("category", "%");
else query.setParameter("category", category);

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE CATEGORY=*

I think you are new to SQL, too.

`WHERE CATEGORY = *` does not mean "any category" (it is not even valid SQL).

In both SQL and JPA, you would just not have the `WHERE` clause at all if you want any category (or in SQL you could have `WHERE CATEGORY IS NOT NULL`).

Comment: sorry for the wrong SQL query:)

Your solution  "WHERE CATEGORY IS NOT NULL" is good, but I have to create another query. 

Is there any other way can save one query?

Answer (score 0):

[Pascal Thivent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70604/pascal-thivent) gave pretty good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2439958/5898696) recommending using `Criteria`. However the `Criteria` in his answer is pure `Hibernate` criteria. Using `JPA Criteria` example:

```
private List<Result> getProduct(String category) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Product> criteria = builder.createQuery(Product.class);
    Root<Product> productRoot = criteria.from(Product.class);

    if (category != null)
        criteria.where(builder.equal(productRoot.get("category"), category))    
    }

    entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying to achieve is counter intuitive in terms of design pattern. Let's think of the problems in SQL terms ignoring all JPA and other.

The corresponding SQL query of your JPQL looks like below

```
SELECT o.* FROM product o WHERE o.category = 'SOME_CAT';
```

Now if you pass null instead of category `SOME_CAT` the SQL would be like

```
SELECT o.* FROM product o WHERE o.category IS NULL;
```

There is no SQL standard to invert the result set altering param value unless your SQL looks like following

```
SELECT o.* FROM product o WHERE o.category IS NOT NULL;
```

The similar JPQL will look like

```
SELECT o FROM Product o WHERE o.category <> :param
```

You can see that we need to invert the logical operation instead of manipulating the param. There is no standard way to achive this behavior unless you build JPQL dynamically with if else condition.

I would prefer a separate method handler one for filtering with category and other for listing all regardless of category.