# Without setting a parameter of named query?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

For example I have a named query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Students", query = "SELECT s FROM Student WHERE s.active = 'Y' OR s.name= :name)
```

Sometimes I wanna set the 'name' parameter with a value and sometimes not. Does it cause an error when I don't set it?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444603/optional-parameters-with-named-query-in-hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution like this:

```
if (my test criteria){
     query.setParameter("name", "name of a student");
  }  else {
     query.setParameter("name", " ");
  }
```

I am setting the name parameter with whitespace character so it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set it always. Otherwise - create two queries - one with param, and one without. You can place the common part in a constant (`static final`)