# Envers optional predicates

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have an envers query to look up the history of a given entity, what I am trying to do is make use of the predicates if they are specified in the request.

For example I would like the ability to filter by date/user/revision type etc (or a combination of fields) based on the request sent.

I know how to add predicates, I'm just wondering is there a default value I can use if the parameter (for example `fromDate`) is not specified and therefore the following line is ignored.

```
.add(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("date").ge(fromDate))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From further reading on this i've found the solution to be similar to this answer;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2439958/7030856

```
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(cls, true, true);
if (fromDate!= null) {
    query.add(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("date").ge(fromDate))
}
// Etc
List<Object[]> changes = query.getResultList();
```