# Hibernate - where clause any with collection as a named parameter query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm wondering if is possible to make this kind of evaluation with collections like the query isn't working in my project at a class named query as follow:

```
@NamedQueries(value = {  
@NamedQuery(
name = "Foo.getBarList", 
query = "select f from Foo f where (:barlist is null or f.barlist.id in (:barslist)) " )})
```

from this both post:

`FROM Foo WHERE Id = :id AND (:barlist is null or Bar in (:barlist))` 
[JPA where clause any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437053/jpa-where-clause-any/2725096#2725096)

[Hibernate HQL Query : How to set a Collection as a named parameter of a Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570229/hibernate-hql-query-how-to-set-a-collection-as-a-named-parameter-of-a-query)

I guess the problem was the id in query so I remove and the error stop, just change this:
  `"select f from Foo f where (:barlist is null or f.barlist in (:barslist)) "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of in HQL you can check

```
if(barlist==null){
    //query=FROM Foo WHERE Id = :id
}else{
   //query=FROM Foo WHERE Id = :id AND Bar in :barlist
   // query.setParameterList(:barlist",<list object>)
}
```

Comment: Thanks to point a way, but I will end with 2 named queries like: `@NamedQueries(value = {
  @NamedQuery(name = "Foo.get",
    query = "select e from Foo e "
      + " where (:id is null or e.id = :id) "
      
      
    ),
  @NamedQuery(name = "Foo.getBarList",
  query = "select e from Foo e "
    + " where (:id is null or e.id = :id) "
    
    + " and (:barlist is null or e.barlist.id in (:barslist)) "
    
  )})` and the DAO code will handle a strategy if then else there too.

Comment: the DAO code will handle a strategy if then else there too as like: `Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
   String sql = "";
   if(f.getBarList().isEmpty())
    sql = "Foo.get";
   else
    sql = "Foo.getBarList";
   Query query = session.getNamedQuery(sql);
   if(!f.getBarList().isEmpty())
    query.setParameterList("barlist", f.getBarList());`

Comment: you can also try this to check whether parameter is there in query ..
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#getNamedParameters()