# Creating a "where in" HQL query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql, where-in

I am having trouble writing a HQL query which uses a "where in" clause.

Simplified classes look like this:

```
class Parent
{
    public virtual Int64 Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; private set; }
}

class Child
{
    public virtual Int64 Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; private set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; private set; }
}
```

With mapping defined like this:

```
class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Name);
}

class ChildMap : ClassMap<Child>
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Name);
    References(x => x.Parent);
}
```

I wanted to get `Child` instances which belong to certain `Parent` items, so I wrote the following code:

```
// get children for several parents (a flattened list)
IEnumerable<Parent> parents = GetParents();

// use hql
IQuery q = Session.CreateQuery("from Child as c where c.Parent in (:parents)");
q.SetParameter("parents", parents);
```

but the problem is, I am getting the following exception at `q.SetParameter`:

```
Test method Can_get_children_for_many_parents threw exception:
  NHibernate.PropertyAccessException:
  Exception occurred getter of Some.Namespace.Parent.Id 
  ---> System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
```

**[Edit]**

I tried using `q.SetParameter("parents", parents.Select(p => p.Id);`, but I get the same exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
q.SetParameterList("parents", parents.ToList());
```

Comment: +1, thanks, I just found it in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570229/hibernate-hql-query-how-to-set-a-collection-as-a-named-parameter-of-a-query). `parents` is of type `IEnumerable<Parent>` in my case.

Comment: +1 for `SetParameterList`, but why `parents.Split` and not `parents.ToArray()`??

Comment: @stefan: that's a portion of code I used. I guess the result is the same (assuming the data is always correct)