# Deleting multiple rows in a one statement

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sql-delete

I have some trivial table in database (let say Oracle10g) and I need to implement at **DAO** ability to delete multiple records. The method `remove()` receives as a parameter an array of ids (integers).

For now I have a query string `"DELETE FROM news WHERE id = ?"` which I use at **PreparedStatement**. I simply add batch for every id from array and then perform execute on **PreparedStatement**.

I wonder if there any ability to perform it through one query statement, something like `"DELETE FROM news WHERE id IN ?"`. But I cannot find how to properly set an array of integers instead of `'?'`.

The same question applies to **Hibernate** and **JPA**. If there any constructions to solve this ? Because now I use batch-like-way: add **Query** to **Session** on every id from array and commit transaction.

Comment: See this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/189399/851432. It points to a [link](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2) which may be useful in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best I've seen done is to dynamically build the String used by the PreparedStatement, inserting the proper # of `?,` sequences, then use a for loop to call `setInt` as appropriate for each row - each row to be deleted in your case.

JPA provides a special syntax for this (can accept a `Collection` to populate the list of arguments), since it has to create the SQL anyway - and likely does so very similar to how I just described.  Specifics as to the API calls (for both JPA and HQL) are available at [Hibernate HQL Query : How to set a Collection as a named parameter of a Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570229/hibernate-hql-query-how-to-set-a-collection-as-a-named-parameter-of-a-query) .