# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, hibernate, classcastexception

when I am running this code its giving me exception 
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String on q1.list();

```
Query q=session.createQuery("select categoryData FROM SearchHistoryEntity where userId=:u");
q.setInteger("u", userId);
List<String> list1=q.list();
if(list1!=null){
Query q1=session.createQuery("FROM BookEntity where category in (:names) order by bookId");
q1.setParameter("names", list1);
if(q1.list().size()>9){  
    q1.setFirstResult(1);
    q1.setMaxResults(9);
}
list=new ArrayList<BookEntity>();
list=q1.list();
```

this is the full stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/BookStore] threw        exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException:     java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringTypeDescriptor.unwrap(StringTypeDescriptor.java:39)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:64)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:90)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:286)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:281)
at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:67)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:613)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
at com.app.dao.hib.SearchHistoryDaoImpl.categoryData(SearchHistoryDaoImpl.java:150)
at com.app.service.impl.SearchHistoryServiceImpl.recommend(SearchHistoryServiceImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at $Proxy37.recommend(Unknown Source)
at com.app.controller.UserController.recommend(UserController.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I the above code i am just trying to get the list of titles from SearchHistory table corresponding to a particular userId (which is query q) and then finding the list of books with those titles (query q1) but there is some problem its not working.
can anyone help me with this

Comment: Can you share the source of `Query`? And the full stacktrace?

Comment: i have added full stacktrace and little more description

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate HQL Query : How to set a Collection as a named parameter of a Query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570229/hibernate-hql-query-how-to-set-a-collection-as-a-named-parameter-of-a-query)

Answer (score 23):

Try changing

```
q1.setParameter("names", list1);
```

to

```
q1.setParameterList("names", list1);
```

Answer (score 3):

try like this

```
  List<String> list1= new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add(q);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
q1.setParameterList("names", list1);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 For emaple we have pass data on server through api url and we pass parameter or body 
 parameter value same process is here. we will pass list in parameter in this case:

 q1.setParameterList("names", list1);
```