# HQL; List of Integer as input query

Tags: java, list, hql

I have a `List` composed by `Integer` elements. I have to make a single query like this:

```
 From Table as t where t.id <> element1 AND t.id <> element2 AND ......
```

Someone can give me a tip how to set the input list? I have to set the single element or the entire list?

Answer (score 3):

Create `Collection` of Integers:

```
Collection<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ints.add(1);
ints.add(2);
ints.add(3);
```

Set it as parameter:

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("FROM Table as t WHERE t.id NOT IN (:ints)");
q.setParameterList("ints", ints);
```

Relevant question: [Hibernate HQL Query : How to set a Collection as a named parameter of a Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570229/hibernate-hql-query-how-to-set-a-collection-as-a-named-parameter-of-a-query)

Comment: Ehy thank's it worked! (but i had to use setParameterList instead the simple setParameter). However it's solved now, thx ^^

Comment: Thanks! Improved my answer